# Type is not convertible to 'NativeObject'

Tags: swift, xcode6

Since I updated my Xcode to version 6 beta 3 I'm getting `Type is not convertible to 'NativeObject'` error all over the place.
This is just one case where it's complaining:

```
func createPointsToPath(points:[AnyObject]!) -> CGPathRef {
    let path:CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CFAutorelease(path)

    if(points != nil && points.count > 0){ //this line complains about '[AnyObject]' is not convertible to 'NativeObject'
        var point:CGPoint = (points[0] as NSValue).CGPointValue()
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y)

        println("number of elements in the array \(points.count)")
        for index in 1...points.count - 1  {
            point = (points[index] as NSValue).CGPointValue()
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y)
        }
    }
    return path
}
```

as mentioned in code comment, it's complaining about `'[AnyObject]' is not convertible to 'NativeObject'` where I check `points != nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UPDATE

As of Beta 5, optionals are no longer considered boolean types, and you must explicitly compare to nil. This answer is no longer valid, but for posterity I've left it below. Your original code may work now with the new update, of course, because of the mysteries of the Swift compiler.

### old invalid answer:

You can just say:

```
if points && points.count > 0
```

`nil` evaluates to false with optionals, so this should work.